# Why is Lightning Readiness report showing issues with URL Buttons?

Tags: lightning-experience, weblinks

I was unaware of the fact that Lightning Readiness report is also reporting issues with custom Buttons set to URL as source. I was thinking that only JavaScript Buttons are getting ditched in Lightning Experience.

Is there more information available on this subject where we can read details about what kind of buttons or weblinks are allowed for Lightning Experience? and possibly a little explanation of why would simple URL buttons are going to be issue with Lightning Experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL buttons may not work as you expect in Lightning. Before [Spring 16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_url_button_support_lex.htm), they were not supported at all, but even today, not all pages may handle parameters correctly in both Lightning and Classic:

> If you use URL custom buttons to pass parameters to standard pages in
>   Salesforce Classic—such as pre-populating fields when creating a
>   record—this behavior doesn’t work in Salesforce1 or Lightning
>   Experience.

Note that this only applies to internal links. If you're linking to some arbitrary site, like Google or something, the URL may or may not work depending on the provider's configuration for framing and security.

Comment: The buttons I've, are not interacting with layouts but a custom VF page. Though I do need to pass 1 additional parameter (except `Record Id`) to support my app's intended behavior from a button invocation from record detail view. And Security Review team didn't flag those URL buttons, but this Lightning Ready report is now showing them with red flags.

Comment: @VarunC The report engine just flags everything that's a URL button, because it can't know if the URL will work correctly in Lightning. You need to manually test those buttons in Classic, LEX, and S1 to make sure they work. The Security Review team is only concerned with things like exposing a user's password, elevating privileges, and actual security issues, not technical issues like potential governor limit bugs.

Comment: Well, the buttons do work in Lightning :-), I was just worried for a bit that may be URL button's are getting discontinued for Lightning as well, even though I did recall the Spring 16 release notes confirming these as supported Content Source for Weblinks in Lightning.

Comment: @VarunC If they work, you're good. They just apply a blanket statement to all URL buttons so that orgs won't switch to Lightning just to find out that critical functionality doesn't work.

Comment: Nice Explanation , you are great @sfdcfox